# MAUI Project upgraded from Xamarin Forms: "doesn't have a target for 'net6.0-ios/ios-arm64'"

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui

I have converted a Xamarin project to MAUI project using **Upgrade Assistant** as per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/upgrade-assistant) blog. First I upgraded solution, then I upgraded the android and ios projects. After that I build my solution but I get the below errors.

> Error NETSDK1047  Assets file 'C:\Users\SREEJITH\source\repos\MAUIDemo\MAUIDemo\MAUIDemo.iOS\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net6.0-ios/ios-arm64'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net6.0-ios' in the TargetFrameworks for your project. You may also need to include 'ios-arm64' in your project's RuntimeIdentifiers.
> MAUIDemo.iOS  C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.306\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets    266
> Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace 'Xamarin' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
> MAUIDemo.Android (net6.0-android) C:\Users\SREEJITH\source\repos\MAUIDemo\MAUIDemo\MAUIDemo.Android\MainActivity.cs   11  Active
> Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Content' does not exist in the namespace 'MAUIDemo.Android' ...
> Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Essentials' does not exist in the namespace 'Xamarin' ...
> Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace 'Xamarin' ...
> Error   CS0103  The name 'LoadApplication' does not exist in the current context    MAUIDemo.Android (net6.0-android)   C:\Users\SREEJITH\source\repos\MAUIDemo\MAUIDemo\MAUIDemo.Android\MainActivity.cs   19  Active
> ...

**Screenshot:**

[image]

[image]

I have a few questions related to this:

1. I upgraded the solution, android and iOS projects. Is solution upgrade is enough or do we need to upgrade the android and iOS projects?
2. When I create a new MAUI project, I found there is a `Platforms` folder and on that I found Android and iOS sub folders. But when upgrade no such folders are created on my side, should I create it manually?
3. Below is the project structure of a MAUI project created. Like that do I need to create all the files and folders?

[image]

**Update**

Below issues are currently I am facing:

> 1. Error : XamlC error XFC0000 : Cannot resolve type "ContentPage".
> 2. Error : XamlC error XFC0000 : Cannot resolve type "Frame".
> 3. Error : XamlC error XFC0000 : Cannot resolve type "Application".
> 4. Project targets 'net6.0-android;net6.0-ios'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v13.0'.
> 5. Project targets 'net6.0-android;net6.0-ios'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets 'Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0'.
> 6. Project is not compatible with monoandroid13.0 Project supports:
>    net6.0-android31.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)
>    net6.0-ios16.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)
> 7. Project is not compatible with xamarinios10 Project supports:
>    net6.0-android31.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)
>    net6.0-ios16.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)
> 8. Version conflict detected for Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser. Install/reference Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser 1.4.0.1 directly to project to resolve this issue.
>    Microsoft.Maui.Dependencies 6.0.553 -> Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser (>= 1.4.0.1)
>    Xam.Plugin.HtmlLabel 5.1.0 -> Xamarin.Essentials 1.7.0 -> Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser (>= 1.3.0.5 && < 1.4.0).
> 9. The target platform must be set to Windows (usually by including '-windows' in the TargetFramework property) when using Windows Forms or WPF, or referencing projects or packages that do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Known issue: [Bug: MAUI-Template: net6.0-ios is missing RuntimeIdentifier ios-arm64](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/2979).

- The issue is marked as fixed in latest [.Net 8 Preview](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/8.0).

---

To fix an existing project, add the following to your project's `.csproj` file:

```xml
<PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-ios'))">
    <RuntimeIdentifier>ios-arm64</RuntimeIdentifier>
</PropertyGroup>
```

**UPDATE:**
For a Xamarin Forms to Maui upgrade using Upgrade Assistant, it is the `iOS` project that needs this identifier.

> 1. I upgraded the solution, android and iOS projects. Is solution upgrade is enough or do we need to upgrade the android and iOS projects?

Upgrading the solution upgrades all the projects. Do NOT need to also run upgrade on each project.

> 2. Should I create Platforms folder manually.

No. If you later add another file for a platform, you will add it where the Upgrade Assistant put your files for that platform.

> 3. Project structure.

The structure created by Upgrade Assistant has everything needed. It is not necessary to match the structure created by a new Maui Project Template.

---

**ALTERNATIVE FIX**

You could move the upgraded source files into a new Maui project. This will avoid the problem. And gives you a layout the same as anyone else who creates a new Maui project.

To make a new solution from your existing Xamarin Forms solution:

- Run the Upgrade Assistant on your Xamarin Forms solution. This changes name spaces from Xamarin to Maui.
- Download the latest [.Net 8 Preview](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/8.0).
- Create a New Project with Maui Template.
- Add your source files (xaml, cs) to this new project.
- - The files from shared project go directly into the new maui project's root folder.
- - The files from each platform project (iOS, Android) go into the corresponding platform folder (Platforms/iOS, Platforms/Android).
- - In VS' Solution Explorer, right-click on folder, select "Add Existing Item...", select the file(s) in that disk folder.
- - Select one of the platform projects (ioS or Android) as Startup Project (the one to Run).
- - Build. There may be compilation errors. These have to be fixed manually.

Comment: In which file I need to add the `PropertyGroup`, in main project or ios project?

Comment: Could you please answer the 3 questions I have asked?

Comment: iOS project. I've updated the answer with 3 answers.

Comment: ios issue is resolved. Still `MainActivity` and `AppDelegate` has the same errors like the screenshot in the question and I am working on that. My project is already available on stores. So if we create a new MAUI project and move all the files into it, is it approve by store?  sorry for the late reply

Comment: Pending errors when I upgrade the project using upgrade assistant with .Net 6. Upgraded solution, android and ios.
Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L00VK.png
Pending errors when I upgrade the project using upgrade assistant with .Net 8. Upgraded solution, android and ios.
Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Hp2q.png
Always the solution upgrade is success without skipping any files. But android and ios upgradation skipping a lot of files. Please redirect me what mistake I am doing.

Comment: I think you will have to manually fix those files. Comment out any `using ...` statement that has `Xamarin` in its namespace name. Then go to each error in file, click on the classname that has a red squiggly underline. If a lightbulb appears, pick the option that has `Maui` in the name. If you can't solve some errors, add an `UPDATE` section to question. Show some of the lines with errors. Please add the lines as copyable text, so I can help search for what is wrong. Plus either a screenshot, or text saying which word(s) has the error underline.

Comment: I have 2 questions: 1. My project is already available on stores. So if we create a new MAUI project and move all the files into it, is it approve by store? 2. Which .Net is best for the migration, .Net 6,7 or 8? Could you please answer?

Comment: I have updated the question with outstanding issues, could you please have a look?

Comment: To ask another question, please start a new question post ("Ask Question" button). This keeps each Q&A focused on one issue.