# .Net Maui iOS SDK versions list empty

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui, maui-ios

I have been learning the Xamarin.Forms to .Net Maui upgrade process. I created a new Xamarin.Forms solution with Android and iOS projects with the latest version of Visual Studio, and have upgraded them using the .NET Upgrade Assistant.

A few issues were encountered, but this once I just can't seem to resolve or find info on online. After upgrading the iOS project, when I build I get the error `MinimumOSVersion value in info.plist (8.0) does not match the SupportedOSPlatformVersion value (17.2)`.

My iOS project doesn't have a SupportedOSPlatformVersion element in it, and when editing the project in Visual Studio I noticed the SDK version drop down is empty, which I suspect is part of the issue here.

[image: iOS project settings]

Any idea why this list would be empty?

Note: I need to support at least 15.0, which I've tried setting MinimumOSVersion in info.plist to already, but it gives the same error for (15.0) as (8.0)

Answer (score 0):

For migrating from Xamarin, you can refer to these two threads: [MAUI Project upgraded from Xamarin Forms: "doesn't have a target for 'net6.0-ios/ios-arm64'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76834874/maui-project-upgraded-from-xamarin-forms-doesnt-have-a-target-for-net6-0-ios/76838564#76838564) | [Upgrade from Xamarin Forms to Maui disables selection of emulator or connected device](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76857990/19902734).  Especially the latter.

And to be honest, it's more recommended to choose [`Manually upgrade a Xamarin.Forms app to a single project .NET MAUI app`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/multi-project-to-single-project?view=net-maui-8.0). This can avoid some trivial issues e.g. version mismatch.